Unable To Change TextBox Value
I am passing value from one form to another and the value from second form is from DataGridView. I can see it passes data perfectly when debugging in the first form and did as follows:
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    txtResult.Enabled = false;
}

public Form1(string exp, double res, string lastExp)
{
    setExp = exp;
    setRes = res;
    setLastExp = lastExp;

    if (lastExp.Length > 0)
    {
        input += lastExp;
    }

    InitializeComponent();

    this.textBox1.Clear();
    this.textBox1.Text = "";
    input += setRes.ToString();
    this.textBox1.Text += input; //Unfortunately this remains the same, even the value gets changed from the second form
}

How can I force to update the TextBox value depending upon changes from second form?

Make this modification and tell me

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtResult.Enabled = false;

        // Initialize the text box with the default values
        textBox1.Text = "";
        UpdateTextBox();
    }

    public Form1(string exp, double res, string lastExp) : this()
    {
        setExp = exp;
        setRes = res;
        setLastExp = lastExp;

        // Update the text box with the new values
        UpdateTextBox();

        // Ensure the form is visible after updating
        this.Show();
    }

    // Method to update the text box with the current values
    private void UpdateTextBox()
    {
        string input = "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(setLastExp))
        {
            input += setLastExp;
        }

        input += setRes.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = input;

        // Refresh or invalidate the text box to force a display update
        textBox1.Refresh(); // Or textBox1.Invalidate();
    }




Doesn't change the previous value @Rachad.

try this in you condition : if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(setLastExp))

It doesn't have null or empty though. When I debug, the value is placed in the TextBox, but not rendered in the front-end.

try now to inittialize and tell me

This worked but it doesn't close the previous window, two forms remain opened; one with previous TextBox values, the other one with new values. Is it possible to close the previous one?

You need to add other attribute references to your previous form

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
